# What does this operator mean "<<="?

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to read this javascript code but I'm unsure of what it does due to this operator I've never seen before. As of now, I have no way of testing the code. <<=

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var temp = 14;
var y = 2;
temp <<= y;
document.write(temp);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [left shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Left_shift_assignment)

Comment: Is this part of a homework question or something? This exact question was asked a year ago @ yahoo. https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141127124911AAEA1h8

Comment: @DamienOvereem Yes, its part of homework

Comment: @MaxGetman Guess quite a few more of your peers copy-pasted their homework assignments on Q&A sites. I guess you missed the class where your teacher explained what "<<=" meant :)

Comment: @DamienOvereem Haha, if only it were true, I ended up teaching the class what it meant as my teacher didn't explain it, nor know how to code for it in LMC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the left shift assignment operator, which is a shortcut for this statement:

```
temp = temp << y;
```

The bit-shift `<<` operator takes the binary representation of `temp` (which is `1110`) and shifts it to the left `y` times (you can see this as appending `y` zeroes to the right). After the `<<` takes place, `1110` becomes `111000`, which in decimal is `56`.

Answer (score 0):

x << = y is shortcut for left shift: x = x << y

> Shifts a in binary representation b (<32) bits to the left, shifting
>   in zeroes from the right.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 0):

In the java Script "<<=" is Left shift assignment operator that moves the specified amount of bits to the left and assigns the result to the variable.

[You can find Description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)